# PanacheQuery: Operators to allow Case Insensitive queries

Tags: quarkus-panache

I am trying to create a query which has the following 2 criteria:

1. Should be partial string match instead of an exact match
2. Should be case insensitive

My query is currently like this:

```
return list("company=?1 and name?=2", company, name);
```

However this doesn't do partial string match. Is there an operator for this?

Just for clarity's sake, assuming the DB contains `peter, Peter, peTeR`, a query for `name=peter` should return all 3 names.

Answer (score 0):

You can partially match strings using the `LIKE` operator combined with the `CONCAT` function like this:

```
company like concat('%', ?1, '%')
```

You can match strings case-insensitively using the `LOWER` function like this:

```
lower(name) = lower(?2)
```

You can also combine both to match the `company` and the `name` partially and case-insensitively:

```java
return list("lower(company) like concat('%', lower(?1), '%') and lower(name) like concat('%', lower(?2), '%')", company, name);
```